# What's left of "Pin tab" in Chrome? Are they just useless?

Tags: google-chrome, pinning

What I liked about pinned tabs in Chrome was that when you entered a new URL in the address bar it opened in a new tab, leaving the pinned one unaffected. For some time now they don't do that. :( I'm wondering what are they for now? To have a smaller label? And that's it? What am I missing?

Comment: Just for the record, I disagree with closure of this thread, the question has been answered, even though it does not make me happy at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome remembers them during restarts. They don't have any close protection or new tab opening.

You can however make them somewhat permanent by adding command line switches to the Chrome shortcut.

Go into the shortcut's properties, then add the following line after the location in the "Target" box. Substitute x with the number of pinned tabs you want.

```
- -pinned-tab-count=x [urls in here sepererated by spaces]
```

That will make the urls you put in load on startup as pinned tabs.

Comment: Thanks but I don't care about restarts that much: 1) I don't close browser at all, having GMail in the first tab 2) I have "re-open tabs" On... So it seems like another nice feature has been dropped from Chrome. (After Ctrl+M for new window with different user profile.)